# Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user, error code 0x6ba

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

When I run

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_logininfo [DOMAIN_B\GroupName],'members'
```

I am getting an error:

```
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DOMAIN_B\GroupName ', error code 0x6ba.
```

The SQL Server instance (MS SQL Server 2019 Standard edition, named instance) is installed on the machine in another domain, eg. DOMAIN_A.
The service account for SQL Server database engine is (for test reasons) domain admin in DOMAIN_B.

I can create a login for Windows Group (DOMAIN_B\GroupName) or individual user of the DOMAIN_B without any problems or errors – so the instance can communicate with the DC/AD.

0x6ba = 1722 The RPC Server is Unavailable error – we’ve checked almost every issue about this error found on the internet (on DC or remote computer) with no success – everything seems fine, replication is finished, all services are running, no firewall or permission issues.

Any ideas what else to check to be able to list the members of the Windows Group on SQL Server instance (need it for application purposes)?

Comment: I don't have the means to test it, but see if [Dsquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc754232(v=ws.11)) can help. Just a second option if you can't fix `xp_logininfo`.

Comment: Thanks @Ronaldo for pointing me to this tool. This subject is bit out of my scope but I was googeling a bit and I'll ask AD guys to try Dsget tool to list members at the machine where SQL Server is installed and run it under SQL Server service account is running - do you thing that would be usable for testing purposes?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with that. The subject is out of my scope too and I suggested that tool from the research I did after seeing your question. In fact I think you're ahead of me because I just remembered one time I needed to get login info from AD groups and instead of using `xp_logininfo` as you did I used `xp_cmdshell` to issue a `net group /domain groupname`.